# Why Is Excel Skipping Rows On A Certain Column When Importing From Flat File?

Tags: excel, import

I am importing about 5000 rows from `Flat Flat` into `Excel`.

It is skipping certain rows for a particular column.  Why is this?   To be more concise my example results (that I don't want) looks something like this:

```
A     |B     |C     |
---------------------
xxxx  |xxxxx |xxxxxx|
xxxx  |      |xxxxxx|
xxxx  |xxxxx |xxxxxx|
xxxx  |xxxxx |xxxxxx|
xxxx  |      |xxxxxx|
      |xxxxx |      |
      |xxxxx |      |
```

I need this data imported to create a report and am being hounded because it was needed hours ago.  I can't figure out why this is doing this.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question.  You may have better luck on [superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: @DSM Well its part of a BIG SSIS package.  Was just giving the relevant info.  It is a programming question because I PROGRAMMED the SSIS process

Comment: If it's a programming question, where's the code you need help finding the bug in?  Where's the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  (You may not believe this, but I'm trying to be helpful; you're far likelier to get a quick answer if you post somewhere with a lot of Excel users.  YMMV, of course.)

Comment: I found the problem....It is whenever there is a space it going to next row.